# Change Textblock foreground inside DataTemplate depending on a date bound

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an Accordion from WPF toolkit where I Bind values

```
   <layoutToolkit:Accordion x:Name="myAccordion">
        <layoutToolkit:Accordion.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="myHeader" Text="{Binding Date}" />
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                  <local:BeforeTodayConverter x:Key="IsBeforeToday" />
                </DataTemplate.Resources>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger 
                    Binding="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource IsBeforeToday}}" 
                    Value="True">
                 <Setter 
                    TargetName="myHeader" 
                    Property="Foreground" 
                    Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </layoutToolkit:Accordion.ItemTemplate>
        <layoutToolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               //not important
            </DataTemplate>
        </layoutToolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
    </layoutToolkit:Accordion>
```

Converter :

```
public class BeforeTodayConverter : IValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (!(value is DateTime))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return ((DateTime)value).CompareTo(DateTime.Today) < 0;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

}
What I want is to change the foreground of the textblock "myHeader" depending on the date bound. If the date is anteriour from today's date I want it to be Blue, and if the date is posterior from today's date I want it to be Red.

Is there any way to work this around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a value converter to compare dates:

```
public class BeforeTodayConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is DateTime))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return ((DateTime)value).CompareTo(DateTime.Today) < 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And use it in the template like so:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock 
        x:Name="myHeader" 
        Text="{Binding Date}" 
        Foreground="Red" 
        />
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <local:BeforeTodayConverter x:Key="IsBeforeToday" />
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
            Binding="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource IsBeforeToday}}" 
            Value="True"
            >
            <Setter 
                TargetName="myHeader" 
                Property="Foreground" 
                Value="Blue" 
                />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I'm trying to implement that it doesn't seem to work, i don't get no errors, but the headers are still red

Comment: @281 Please add your version of my solution to your question.

Comment: thank you i got it to work, i just didnt realise at first that the date i was binding was a string... but now it works perfectly !